Generate a regular numeric sequence by increments of 3 BUT considering gaps in the input
Say I have a sequence like myseq below. It is a DNA sequence, so each group of 3 letters make for one letter (aminoacid) in the accompanying myaa sequence. It has a length of 13aa.
I want to create a mydf dataframe with the start and end positions of each group of 3 letters in myseq. In the basic example below without gaps, I do this easily with seq().
myseq <- "CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGTTATTCAGCTAGCATG"
myaa <- "XYZWWXZZVVYZX"
st_pos <- seq(1, nchar(myseq)-2, 3)
en_pos <- seq(3, nchar(myseq), 3)
mydf <- data.frame(starts=st_pos, ends=en_pos, label=unlist(strsplit(myaa, "")))

This produces this dataframe, which is exactly what I want:
> mydf
   starts ends label
1       1    3     X
2       4    6     Y
3       7    9     Z
4      10   12     W
5      13   15     W
6      16   18     X
7      19   21     Z
8      22   24     Z
9      25   27     V
10     28   30     V
11     31   33     Y
12     34   36     Z
13     37   39     X

However, I am encountering examples with my real data where myseq contains gaps. In these cases I cannot rely on seq() because I need to account for the gaps for the start and end positions.
How should I go about it? I show you 2 cases below, and my expected mydf dataframe, for which I just hard coded the start and end positions.
#case 1 - gaps breaking groups of 3 letters in half
myseq <- "CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGTT---ATTC--AGCTAGCATG"
st_pos <- c(1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,31,36,39,42)
en_pos <- c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,35,38,41,44)
mydf <- data.frame(starts=st_pos, ends=en_pos, label=unlist(strsplit(myaa, "")))

#case 2 - gaps in between groups of 3 letters, and at the beginning of groups of 3 letters
myseq <- "CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGT---TAT--TCAGCTAGCATG"
st_pos <- c(1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,28,33,36,39,42)
en_pos <- c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,35,38,41,44)
mydf <- data.frame(starts=st_pos, ends=en_pos, label=unlist(strsplit(myaa, "")))

How should I produce the st_pos and en_pos vectors in these cases in an easy way?
EDIT
To get these numbers, I just split the sequences in groups of 3 letters and count the positions manually, but I don't know how to accomplish that in an automatic way.
For case 1 sequence start positions:
1    4    7    10   13   16   19   22   25      31     36   39   42
CTA  CGT  AGC  TAG  CTG  GGG  TAC  CGT  T---AT  TC--A  GCT  AGC  ATG

Likewise for case 1 end positions:
  3    6    9    12   15   18   21   24      30     35   38   41   44
CTA  CGT  AGC  TAG  CTG  GGG  TAC  CGT  T---AT  TC--A  GCT  AGC  ATG

Now for case 2 sequence start positions:
1    4    7    10   13   16   19   22        28       33   36   39   42
CTA  CGT  AGC  TAG  CTG  GGG  TAC  CGT  ---  TAT  --  TCA  GCT  AGC  ATG

And case 2 end positions:
  3    6    9    12   15   18   21   24        30       35   38   41   44
CTA  CGT  AGC  TAG  CTG  GGG  TAC  CGT  ---  TAT  --  TCA  GCT  AGC  ATG


I cannot understand what you are doing even with the first example (no gaps). Where are the 3 consecutive letters? I see only "GGGG". And why does the value for en_pos equal the next value for st_pos?

imagine the sequence split in 3s like CTA CGT AGC TAG CTG GGG TAC CGT TAT TCA GCT AGC ATG, I want all the start positions of each group so 1, 4, 7, 10... and all the end positions; I agree these would be 3, 6, 9, 12... but for my purposes (this goes into plotting adjacent segments) I'd rather have them as 4, 7, 10, 13

Now if you do the same with the case 1 sequence: CTA CGT AGC TAG CTG GGG TAC CGT T---AT TC--A GCT AGC ATG you cannot apply seq() anymore, cause there are a couple of groups of 3s that now are length 6 and 5 respectively (cause I need to account for the gaps in those groups)

See my edit, it might make things clearer

Please check the start/end positions for the last example. Should row #9 (start=29, end=32) be 28 / 33? And row #10 needs checking as well.

let me check and edit again, I think for simplicity Im just going to leave true end positions (not +1)

just checked all the numbers, it is correct now, remember that gaps should be counted for the start and end positions; for simplicity, I put the true end positions (without the +1)

Try the following, which identifies the index of any upper-case letter in the sequence using grep and then creates the start and end positions from this.
Case #1

myseq <- "CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGTT---ATTC--AGCTAGCATG"

idx <- grep("[A-Z]", unlist(strsplit(myseq, "")))
data.frame(st_pos=idx[seq(1, length(idx), 3)], 
           en_pos=idx[seq(3, length(idx), 3)])

Gives:
   st_pos en_pos
1       1      3
2       4      6
3       7      9
4      10     12
5      13     15
6      16     18
7      19     21
8      22     24
9      25     30
10     31     35
11     36     38
12     39     41
13     42     44

which matches your expected output.

Case #2
myseq <- "CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGT---TAT--TCAGCTAGCATG"

idx <- grep("[A-Z]", unlist(strsplit(myseq, "")))
data.frame(st_pos=idx[seq(1, length(idx), 3)], 
           en_pos=idx[seq(3, length(idx), 3)])

Gives
   st_pos en_pos
1       1      3
2       4      6
3       7      9
4      10     12
5      13     15
6      16     18
7      19     21
8      22     24
9      28     30
10     33     35
11     36     38
12     39     41
13     42     44

Which also matches your expected output.

Ah this is exactly where I was trying to get at! Thanks!

You could try something like this:
> f <- \(string, n=3) {
+   chr <- el(strsplit(string, ''))
+   mat <- matrix(split(chr, cumsum(chr != '-')), n)
+   strings3 <- apply(mat, 2, \(x) paste(unlist(x), collapse=''))
+   lens <- cumsum(nchar(strings3))
+   cbind(c(1, lens + 1L)[-(length(lens) + 1L)], lens + 1L)
+ }
> 
> f("CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGTTATTCAGCTAGCATG")
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    4
 [2,]    4    7
 [3,]    7   10
 [4,]   10   13
 [5,]   13   16
 [6,]   16   19
 [7,]   19   22
 [8,]   22   25
 [9,]   25   28
[10,]   28   31
[11,]   31   34
[12,]   34   37
[13,]   37   40
> f("CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGTT---ATTC--AGCTAGCATG")
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    4
 [2,]    4    7
 [3,]    7   10
 [4,]   10   13
 [5,]   13   16
 [6,]   16   19
 [7,]   19   22
 [8,]   22   25
 [9,]   25   31
[10,]   31   36
[11,]   36   39
[12,]   39   42
[13,]   42   45
> f("CTACGTAGCTAGCTGGGGTACCGT---TAT--TCAGCTAGCATG")
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    4
 [2,]    4    7
 [3,]    7   10
 [4,]   10   13
 [5,]   13   16
 [6,]   16   19
 [7,]   19   22
 [8,]   22   28
 [9,]   28   33
[10,]   33   36
[11,]   36   39
[12,]   39   42
[13,]   42   45


hmmm this does not look correct, the numbers are different from my st_pos and en_pos in example case 1, and the length should be 13 (same as myaa) not 15...

@DaniCee I know, but I believe it's the right way. I'm about deleting this but you can still contribute with your thoughts.

@DaniCee Obviousy row 15 can be deleted, since it restarts with 1. But why is {25, 29} deleted?

If you separate the case 1 sequence in groups of 3s like this: CTA CGT AGC TAG CTG GGG TAC CGT T---AT TC--A GCT AGC ATG you can count that the start position of group T---AT is at 25 and ends at 30 (so I put my end position at 31), then the group TC--A starts at 31 and ends at 35 (so I put my end position at 36)... so from row 9 in your matrix the numbers should be different, just not sure how to accomplish that

See my edit, it might make things clearer

I just updated the edit to account for case 2 as well, see if that makes it clearer

@DaniCee See update, seems to be better.

ah seems much better! but why is the last row 45-45 instead of 42-45 in both cases?

@DaniCee Oh, didn't notice, we need to add 1 to get the last element removed. Updated.

@DaniCee As you may have already realized, the solution split-counts your third example like CTA, CGT, AGC, TAG, CTG, GGG, TAC, CGT---, TAT--, TCA, GCT, AGC, ATG. T could be either be counted 25 or 28, not sure which is better.
